# How can I improve this stored procedure to account for spaces, commas, or incorrect input?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Thanks for taking the time to look at my post. I have a database of names that may possibly be in different columns. Like Name1, Name2, MiddleName, LastName, etc. I need for someone to be able to search the table with a few different formats as follows:

SearchQuery = "John Smith", "Smith, John", " John Smith ", "Smith", " John Smith ", "John, Smith"

Basically if someone were to search in any of the formats above I need to be able to trim spaces, commas, etc. and put it into a format that will return the correct record.

My Code right now is as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchWatchLists]
@firstName NVARCHAR(100)
,@middleName NVARCHAR(100)
,@lastName NVARCHAR(100)
,@suffix NVARCHAR(100)
,@dateOfBirth SMALLDATETIME
,@addressLine1 NVARCHAR(100)
,@addressLine2 NVARCHAR(100)
,@city NVARCHAR(100)
,@state NVARCHAR(100)
,@country NVARCHAR(100)
,@postalCode NVARCHAR(100)
,@taxid VARCHAR(100)
,@searchType INT -- 0=Exact Match, 1=Near Match, 2=Loose Match
,@sourceCodeHits VARCHAR(MAX) OUT
,@fullHitData XML OUT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRY 
    DECLARE @watchHits TABLE ( sourceCode VARCHAR(50), watchHit XML )
    DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(500), @address NVARCHAR(1000) 

    SELECT @firstName = RTRIM(LTRIM(IsNull(@firstName,'')))
          ,@middleName = RTRIM(LTRIM(IsNull(@middleName,'')))
          ,@lastName = RTRIM(LTRIM(IsNull(@lastName,'')))
          ,@suffix = RTRIM(LTRIM(IsNull(@suffix,'')))
          ,@taxid = RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(IsNull(@taxid,''),'-','')))
          ,@sourceCodeHits = ''
          ,@fullHitData = ''

    SET @name = @firstName
    IF LEN(@middleName) > 0 SET @name += ' ' + @middleName
    IF LEN(@lastName) > 0 SET @name += ' ' + @lastName
    IF LEN(@suffix) > 0 SET @name += ' ' + @suffix

    SELECT @address = @addressLine1, @name = RTRIM(LTRIM(@name)), @address = RTRIM(LTRIM(@address))


    DECLARE @firstLastNameSearch NVARCHAR(500) = '%' + @firstName + ' %' + @lastName + ' %'
    DECLARE @firstLastNameSearch2 NVARCHAR(500) = @firstName + ' ' + @lastName
    DECLARE @firstLastNameSearch3 NVARCHAR(500) = '%' + @firstName + ' ' + @lastName
    DECLARE @firstLastNameSearch4 NVARCHAR(500) = @firstName + ' ' + @lastName + '%'
    DECLARE @firstLastNameSearch5 NVARCHAR(500) = '%' + @firstName + ' ' + @lastName + '%'

    DECLARE @lastFirstNameSearch NVARCHAR(500) = '%' + @lastName + '%' + @firstName + '%'
    DECLARE @lastFirstNameSearch2 NVARCHAR(500) = @lastName + ' ' + @firstName
    DECLARE @lastFirstNameSearch3 NVARCHAR(500) = '%' + @lastName + ' ' + @firstName
    DECLARE @lastFirstNameSearch4 NVARCHAR(500) = @lastName + ' ' + @firstName + '%'
    DECLARE @lastFirstNameSearch5 NVARCHAR(500) = '%' + @lastName + ' ' + @firstName + '%'
    DECLARE @lastFirstNameSearch6 NVARCHAR(500) = '% ' + @lastName + ' ' + @firstName + '%'

    --Table
    IF len(@name) > 0 --OR len(@address) > 0 
        INSERT INTO @watchHits ( sourceCode, watchHit )
            SELECT 'TB-INFO', (select a.* for xml path('TB-INFO'),type,elements absent)
            FROM [dbo].[TableName] a
            WHERE [NameofPerson] like @firstLastNameSearch
                OR [NameOfPerson] LIKE @firstLastNameSearch2
                OR [NameOfPerson] LIKE @firstLastNameSearch3
                OR [NameOfPerson] LIKE @firstLastNameSearch4
                OR [NameOfPerson] LIKE @firstLastNameSearch5
                --LASTFIRST
                OR [NameofPerson] like @lastFirstNameSearch
                OR [NameOfPerson] LIKE @lastFirstNameSearch2
                OR [NameOfPerson] LIKE @lastFirstNameSearch3
                OR [NameOfPerson] LIKE @lastFirstNameSearch4
                OR [NameOfPerson] LIKE @lastFirstNameSearch5
END
```

Thanks for looking at my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use the REPLACE.

```
--Name of person without spaces or commas.
(REPLACE(REPLACE(NameofPerson, ' ', ''), ',', '')  LIKE '%' + @firstName + @lastName + '%') OR
(REPLACE(REPLACE(NameofPerson, ' ', ''), ',', '')  LIKE '%' + @lastName + @firstName + '%'))
```

And then, you can compare with your combinations, but combinations would be easier now.

So, if we introduce  "John Smith", "Smith, John", " John Smith ", "Smith", " John Smith ", "John, Smith", after removing spaces and commas, we will have "JohnSmith" or "Smith" or "SmithJohn" and we can compare them...

Makes sense? Is that what you are looking for?

I understand that NameOfPerson will be the one with the formatted value (John, Smith) and @first, @lastName, etc the correct ones?

EDIT:
I tried this and it works.

```
declare @firstname nvarchar(150) = 'John' --using 'John1' and 'Smith1' will not
declare @lastname nvarchar(150) = 'Smith'

declare @temp table (nameOfPerson nvarchar(150))

insert into @temp values ('John, Smith')

SELECT nameOfPerson
FROM @temp
WHERE
(REPLACE(REPLACE(nameOfPerson, ' ', ''), ',', '')  LIKE '%' + @firstName + @lastName + '%') OR
 (REPLACE(REPLACE(nameOfPerson, ' ', ''), ',', '') LIKE '%' + @lastName + @firstName + '%')
```

Comment: I think this might be what I'm looking for. Let me test it out and get back to you. Thank you for replying!!

Comment: At least this way you will only have 4 conditions (instead of 10), and you will not need to declare the variables either... Also, if the input has 2 commas, or 2 spaces, it will still work.. Let me know if it works!!! No problem!!

Comment: When I switched out those or statements for the ones you provided it returned pretty much every single row.

Comment: so maybe there is something I didn't understand correctly... if @firstName = 'John', and NameofPerson = 'Smith, John'. With that query, we would have:
'SmithJohn' like '%John%'. Which is ok, and it would be returned...

Comment: I should probably clear up the fact that the data stored in the table may be stored as "Smith, John" or "Smith". That is why we need to trim those characters

Comment: the REPLACE should also remove all the spaces... I edited my comment, take a quick look to be sure that's this is the expected result (or I misunderstood the question)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand the question

Comment: when you said about the trim, the REPLACE should also clean the blanks. I just edited my comment, is that how should work? not sure what's wrong then

Comment: Ok I will test out now. Thank you so much for your timely response!

Comment: NO problem! actually, you might be right, you might not need the first 2 fields. so you would only have the first + last (and last + first)

Comment: Also, if firstName and lastName can contain commas and spaces, then you would also need to include the replace there
 LIKE '%' + (REPLACE(REPLACE(@firstName + @lastName, ' ', ''), ',', '') + '%'))

Comment: How would I put the replace() function in a select statement that exports the results to xml. My select statement says 

SELECT 'TBL-INFO', (SELECT A.* FOR XML PATH('TBL-INFO'), TYPE, ELEMENTS ABSENT}

Comment: IF len(@name) > 0 --OR len(@address) > 0 
            INSERT INTO @watchHits ( sourceCode, watchHit )
             SELECT 'TBL-INFO', (select a.* for xml path('TBL-INFO'),type,elements absent)
                  FROM [dbo].[TABLE] a
 Where...

Comment: you wouldn't need it on the select right? at least your current query you doesn't have it. You only use the replace so we can compare them. I think you wouldn't need the replace there, however, in case you do need it, you could just change instead of select a.*, to use a.eachfield, and then the replace where you need it

Comment: I just added it into the select so you could see what you were comparing, but you won't need that part (I think!)